# Homothecy on a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need help proving the next statement:

> Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional real vector space equiped with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.
>
> If $E$ is a measurable set and $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then:
>
> 1. $cE=\{ce:e\in E\}$ is measurable
> 2. $\lambda(cE)=c^n\lambda(E)$.

Is this statement true if we replace:

1. $\mathbb{R}^n$ with any $n$-dimensional vector space.
2. The Lebesgue measure with the Haar measure?

Comment: Hint: $\|c(x-y)\| = c\|x-y\|$ so $cE$ is the image of $E$ under the Lipschitz map $x\mapsto cx$.